# J2EE eclipse file uploading project requires refresh on package explorer before server register new file?

Tags: eclipse

I am using struts to build an image uploading module.

However, I am encountering the problem of user not able to see the file they upload until I manually refresh the package explorer on eclipse.

Any one know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be the option:

```
Preference > General > Workspace > 'Refresh automatically'
```

would help ? (settings for eclipse3.4)

Note: the 'refresh automatically' was [introduced in eclipse3.0](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/platform-core-home/documents/auto_refresh.html?view=co).

There was a [similar issue for CVS file](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg28687.html).

This [article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Resource-deltas/resource-deltas.html) describes what is behind those 'refresh'